# How to save image to storage firebase with external url img? - javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, upload, firebase-storage

I have started to use Firebase. I can upload local file to Firebase Storage.
But now I want to upload a image from external url in input field, example: 
[image]
Can you give to me some suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to pass in a URL to Firebase Storage. You'll have to first download the data from the URL to your client app, and then pass it to the Firebase Storage API.